# HTML ASCII Code for £

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

In my XML document, I have to pass the query string with "£" character and need to retrieve the Job counts result.

While passing query string with "£", does not calculate the correct job postings and gives as 0 for all time.

Please let me know what I need to pass in that xml document to replace "£".

Part of Query string with £:

```
( [salary]: \\\"less than £10,000 \\\" )
```

Comment: There is no ASCII code for the pound sign. ASCII is 7 bit.

Comment: UTF8 code is \u00A3

Comment: That pound-sign, is it a UTF-8 character `£` or the entity `&#163;`? I wouldn't be surprised that if it is stored as the one and you query as the other, that you don't get a match.

Comment: Standard ASCII set : http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: There are no ASCII codes in XML nor in HTML. The document encoding _can_ be ASCII but all character references are Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look here: http://htmlarrows.com/currency/

Try one of these:

```
&pound;

U+000A3

&#xa3;

&#163;
```

Answer (score 2):

In a query string in a URI, non-ASCII characters should be escaped using the %NN convention. The Unicode codepoint for a pound sign (£) -- not to be confused with # which some Americans refer to as a pound sign -- is 163. The UTF-8 encoding of that is the two byte sequence C2-A3, so in a URI you should write %C2%A3.